# Написать программу для приема UDP-пакетов

Tags: udp, ios, macos, objective-c, сокет

Всем доброго времени суток! Мне необходимо написать программу, которая принимала бы udp-пакеты от устройства из локальной сети. В качестве языка желательно использовать Objective-C. Есть ли какие-то готовые решения в этой области? Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: готовое решение называется сокеты. Вам под MacOS писать нужно?

Comment: Под iOS (iPad). Можно писать и на другом языке, но потом будет необходимо все-равно запустить это приложение на iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Откройте для себя сайт developer.apple.com - там куча кода и примеров. Вон [один из них](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html), под Вашу задачу.